# знаки пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Поэтому на вопрос «Можно ли пить Норколут и алкоголь одновременно?» врачи дают отрицательный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

**Есть несколько вариантов оформления подобных предложений**: обычная прямая речь, упрощенная прямая речь (без двоеточия), СПП с частицей ЛИ в качестве союза, БСП с усилительной частицей ЛИ.

1) **На вопрос: «Можно ли** спасти озера?» ― говорят так: «Может быть…»

2) **На вопрос «Можно ли** понять атом?» Н. Бор, подумав, ответил, что, пожалуй, можно, но сначала мы должны узнать, что означает слово «понимание».

3) Чтобы ответить **на вопрос, можно ли** по генетическим данным определить этническую принадлежность человека, были исследованы образцы ДНК.

4) Она продолжала перелопачивать интернет в поисках ответа **на вопрос: можно ли** что-то сделать сейчас, можно ли как-то исправить, восстановить то, что разрушено?

Наибольшей выделительной способностью обладает обычная прямая речь, но такое выделение не всегда нужно. В данном случае лучше выбрать вариант СПП: **Поэтому на вопрос, можно ли пить норколут и алкоголь одновременно, врачи дают отрицательный ответ.**

Answer (score 1):

Если есть слово "вопрос", оформляется, как прямая речь внутри авторских слов.

*Поэтому на вопрос: «Можно ли пить Норколут и алкоголь одновременно?» — врачи дают отрицательный ответ.*

Тире ставится после вопросительного знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь.

Comment: Уважаемый shampar, спасибо за благие намерения, но запятую перед "как" Вы мне зря поставили,здесь нет сравнения, здесь смысл "в качестве" и можно заменить творительным падежом: оформляется прямой речью, а не сравнивается с прямой речью, так что уберите её, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант:

***Поэтому на вопрос,  можно ли пить норколут и алкоголь одновременно, врачи дают отрицательный ответ.***